# Display Jtextfield on JOptionPane.showMessageDialog

Tags: java

I'm having trouble in display the Jtextfield on JOptionPane.showMessageDialog.
It shows something like 
Name: javax swing.Jtextfield[,0,19,195x20,invalid.layout.........
Section: javax swing.Jtextfield[,0,19,195x20,invalid.layout.........
Here is the code:

```
package quiz_application;

import java.awt.Component;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
import javax.swing.JTextField;
/**
*
* @author Christian
*/
public class Quiz_application {
public static void main(String[] args){
 /**
  * Input
  */
 JTextField fullName = new JTextField();
 JTextField section = new JTextField();
 Object[] message = {
"Name:", fullName,
"Section:", section,
 };

 Component parent = null;
 int option = JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(parent, message,"User  Information", JOptionPane.OK_CANCEL_OPTION);
 if (option == JOptionPane.OK_OPTION)
 {
 String value1 = fullName.getText();
 String value2 = section.getText();
 }
 String outputStr="Name: "+ fullName+"\n"
     +"Section: "+ section;

     JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, outputStr,"User Information",JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
  }
 }
```

Comment: `"Name: "+ fullName+"\n"` it should be `"Name: "+ fullName.getText()+"\n"`

Comment: please improve formation in header

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're printing `toString()` of both `JTextField`. I believe you'll only print the User Information dialog if there's one. So, change the `if` statement to around all the rest of the code and now pass `value1` and `value2` to `outputStr` instead of `fullName` and `section`. Or, just call `fullName.getText()` and `section.getText()`. Like that:

**EX1**

```
String value1 = fullName.getText();
String value2 = section.getText();
String outputStr = "Name: " + value1 + "\n" + "Section: " + value2;
```

**EX2**

```
String outputStr = "Name: " + fullName.getText() + "\n" + "Section: " + section.getText();
```

**Expanded `If` Statement**

```
    if (option == JOptionPane.OK_OPTION) {
        String value1 = fullName.getText();
        String value2 = section.getText();

        String outputStr = "Name: " + value1 + "\n" + "Section: " + value2;

        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, outputStr, "User Information",
            JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
    }
```

Comment: Finally, thank you so much. I did try to change fullName and section to value1 and value2 then just found out that I putted the braces on the wrong position.